# Loading a CGpath/UIBezierPath from a remote location

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

Is there any feasible/reasonable way to pass the necessary path info for a `UIBezierPath` from a remote API? I'm interested in downloading shape information at runtime. Here's a dream-code example of what I mean:

```
CGPath path = [APIClient downloadPathInfoForObject:clock];
UIBezierPath *bPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:path];
```

How would you send path info from an API, and subsequently unpack it to a CGPath?

I'll probably end up using regular images, but it would be cool to use CAShapeLayers throughout the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` supports `NSCoding` so you should be able to serialize it with `NSKeyedArchiver`, send it and deserialize it with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` into another `UIBezierPath` at the other location.

**Example**

```
// Get a base64 encoded archive of the path
UIBezierPath *path = UIBezierPath.path;
NSData *pathData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:path];    
NSString *pathString = [pathData base64Encoding]; // Save it to the API

// ...... sometime in the future

NSString *pathString = [APIClient downloadPathForObject:clock]; // Get the string
NSData *pathData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:pathString];
UIBezierPath *path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver pathData]; // Same path!
```

Comment: Thanks, @zaph. This seems like the way to go. I edited your answer to add an example of what exactly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG and some code like [this library](https://github.com/ap4y/UIBezierPath-SVG).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PDF for that. PDFs are the native format for storing/retrieving vector data on iOS. Alternatively, if that's overkill and you are really just after the basic paths without any attributes, you can roll your own simple file format.

Maybe as simple as a text file a bit like that:

```
p 45.0 45.0
l 32.0 32.0
b 50.0 50.3 60 70 80 90.5
l 100.0 100.0
e
```

where p is the command for starting the path at the given coordinates, l is adding a line to the coordinates, b is a bezier curve ending at the last pair of coordinates and e ends the path. Easy to parse.